# How do you access the elements of the array returned from $this->query(select....)?

Tags: sql, arrays, cakephp

I am calling the `query` function from cakephp, and I am selecting two fields from the database. How do I access each field from the array? The query is as such

```
$fieldKeys = $this->query("select FLOWSHEET_NAME, FLOWSHEET_ID from FLOWSHEET_TEMPLATE");
```

And I want to do something along the lines of:

```
foreach($fieldKeys as $value){
        foreach($value as $nest){
            foreach($nest as $id){
                $mapArray[$id[0]] = $id[1];
            }
        }
    }
```

<strike>But this doesn't work.</strike>
This works but $id[0] only gives back the first letter of the string held in the FLOWSHEET_NAME column, whereas I want the whole string.

Comment: what does pr($fieldKeys) return?
it should return an array containing an array keyed on FLOWSHEET_TEMPLATE['FIELD_NAME']

Comment: @nathpiland kindly debug $fielKeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake gives you tools to inspect the array and see for yourself. These tools are `pr($varname)` and `debug($varname)`, but there are other non-cake functions as well.

This is not really a cake question, it's an elementary programming class question.

Answer (score 0):

Your $nest is likely an associative array that you need to loop through like this:

foreach ($nest as $k => $v) {
    foreach($V as $id) {
       ...
    }
}

Comment: The foreach statement actually does work, I'm just not receiving the _whole_ FLOWSHEET_NAME field, just the first character.